# AsyncIO Exceptions in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

In Apache Flink, I'm using the RichAsyncFunction for data enrichment.  In the case of errors/exceptions, I want to funnel those error records into an error stream.  I can see that other functions have a "side output" for this sort of scenario, but how is it handled in RichAsyncFunction?  I also see use of ResultFuture<>.completeExceptionally, but what does this do or mean when it occurs?  Does the stream stop, is it just logged, what is the state with regards to the output element of the stream?  All the docs seem to just point out how to handle the happy path or to call completeExceptionally with no explanation of what happens next.  What is the proper way to handle/capture errors in RichAsyncFunction?

Thanks!